# Effects of changing username (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, username

I would like to change my username on my Kubuntu install and I would just like to know if it will have any negative impact on the system for example programs that will no longer function because of username change etc.

I will find the commands myself I just wanted to know if it will cause any issues, otherwise I will just leave it as is.

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK, nope....

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, the user information is tied to the UID rather than the actual username itself.

This means that a lot of the information will be updated automatically.

You may have to rename the home directory and any groups but as I'm on my mobile it's a little difficult for me to check that.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info. I will look it up on my side in the meantime

Comment: I found this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/34074/how-do-i-change-my-username   thanks for your help!